# Accessing serial data from Neurosky Mindset over bluetooth in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to access the serial data stream being transmitted from the Neurosky Mindset over bluetooth. It is a step in using ThinkGear Communications Protocol mentioned here:

http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=which_api_is_right_for_me

There are a couple programs that should do this for me (Puzzlebox, Mindstream, etc.), I've either had apparently unsolvable dependency issues or they don't do exactly what I want.

I am able to pair the Mindset with my machine using blueman (specifically blueman-manager) I am able to connect the serial port to /dev/rfcomm0. What I am first wondering is: how do I read from this data stream. If I run sdptool records on the device, I get the following output:

Service Name: Dev B
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 3
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100

(I get more than that, but that is the service I'm trying to access.)

I guess my main questions are: If cat /dev/rfcomm0 displays nothing does that mean that there is no data being transmitted? Is the problem that it isn't being displayed because it is raw? Is there a command that will guarantee to give me any serial data if it is being transmitted? Is there a bluetooth standard command that starts SPP transmission (I've searched for documentation for bluez, but that hasn't been too fruitful)?

I have run everything as both root and regular so that doesn't seem to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on something similar myself (native reading of Mindset data in Linux) and will post a follow-up if I get a working implementation. In the meantime, have you seen the python-mindwave project? https://github.com/akloster/python-mindwave/blob/master/parser.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it took a bit of playing around to get the MindSet connected reliably.

The command-line bluetooth tools are more or less useless. The only repeatable way to read off the Mindset (once paired via BlueMan) was to do this:

```
  bash$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
  bash$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
  bash$ sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 00:13:##:##:##:## 1
  bash$ ./mindset_capture.rb
```

...but this reaches EOF before a valid ThinkGear packet has been received.

Instead, pair using Blueman.

Setup:

1. bash$ blueman-manager &
2. enable pairing on MindSet
3. Click Search in BlueMan
4. Select MindSet device
5. Click on Pair
6. Enter PIN (0000)

Connect:

1. bash$ blueman-manager &
2. Right-click on MindSet and select "Connect To: Dev B" (serial connector icon)
3. Run capture utility (e.g. bash$ ./mindset_capture.rb)
4. Right-click on MindSet and select "Disconnect: Dev B"
5. Quit Blueman
6. Restart bluetooth to release rfcomm0 (thanks, BlueMan!)

   bash$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop; sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start

Wouldn't it be better to have a completely command-line driven solution? Yes, yes it would. Unfortunately, the Bluetooth stack on Linux seems to be in a state where the GUI tools and the command line tools do not cooperate -- and the command-line tools do not support pairing (* UPDATE - see comments).

Reading from the device is straightforward. It continuously transmits bytes, so read from it until you encounter two SYNC bytes (0xAA), which mark the beginning of a packet. The structure of the packet is described in **mindset_communications_protocol.pdf**, which is supplied in the MDT.

Ruby code for reading from the MindSet:

```
  require 'rubygems'      # gem install serialport
  require 'serialport' 
  conn = SerialPort.new "/dev/rfcomm0", 57600
  while true
    next if conn.readbyte != 0xAA
    next if conn.readbyte != 0xAA
    while true
      c = conn.readbyte
      break if c == 0xAA
      puts "%02X" % c
    end
  end
```

It's not perfect as it does no real parsing, but that's how bytes are read from the device.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I basically came to the same conclusions though your detail is more thorough and very helpful! My main problem was that (at the time of asking that question) was not authorizing before trying to read data. I decided the easiest way to pair effectively was to just do it by hand each time using blueman-manager...though I'm going to look more closely at what you're doing when I have the chance.

I've decided to just write a reader/parser in C. It wasn't that bad after I read http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/. Though it would be nice to pair from command line...

Comment: I suppose I should update this before some pedantic maintainer of the Linux Bluetooth stack stumbles upon this post and takes umbrage. The command line tools *do* support pairing (via bluez-simple-agent), but rfcomm connect does not create a usable SPP connection. It seems (from a cursory scan of http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/) that the rfcomm utility expects the user to create the actual Bluetooth socket to the serial device it creates, and that Blueman takes care of this for you.

Comment: How do you pair with with bluez-simple-agent? I actually tried that but couldn't get it working and I haven't found any documentation. If you don't mind me asking, what steps did you use to get it to pair? Also on the other note, I do have the socket stuff working in C...once I get it integrated with the Neurosky-provided thinkgear parcer c file (I could write it myself, but their code is pretty nice and reinventing the wheel ain't smart) I'll post the code here.

Comment: Use `hcitool scan` to get the bluetooth address of the Mindset. The use `bluez-simple-agent hci0 00:13:##:##:##:##` to pair, and enter the PIN when prompted (in terminal). If the 'already paired' error comes up, use `bluez-simple-agent hci0 00:13:##:##:##:## remove` to unpair, then try pairing again. Note that you should remove the Mindset from BlueMan, `kill all blueman-manager`, `killall blueman-applet`, and restart the bluetooth subsystem (/etc/init.d/bluetooth) before trying this.

Comment: Great thanks that got it working! It would be nice if I could figure out how to do this in one swoop in C as well, but this is way better than needing to deal with blueman (which is normally great, but has annoying extras for this simpler situation). Thanks again!

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this after playing a bit with bluez tonight. I was able to get a useful rfcomm connection on channel 3, not 1. Steps: 1) pair with bluez-simple-agent as described above, 2) use `hcitool con` to verify the connection, 3) `rfcomm /dev/rfcomm0 00:13:##:##:##:## 3` in a terminal, 4) run your capture utility, 5) Ctrl-C the rfcomm terminal when done. Wotks *much* more reliable than blueman-manager!

Answer (score 1):

I have the old NeuroSky Mindwave and BrainLink_Lite neurogadgets and here I used BrainLink. Neurosky and Brainlink work in the same way using the same protocol cause BrainLink used NeuroSky chip ([TGAM](http://neurosky.com/biosensors/eeg-sensor/biosensors/)). I solved that problem follow the next road:

first I get:

```
$ dmesg | tail -n 50
....
[243709.823581] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[243709.839507] Bluetooth: hci0: ShisiusStation
[243709.840576] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[243709.840606] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3404.hcd failed with error -2
[243709.840608] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3404.hcd not found
...
```

after connection via **blueman-manager** I get in **dmesg output**:

```
[254803.943803] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[254804.299425] Bluetooth: bad checksum in packet
[254817.417375] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[254817.417498] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[254823.416967] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[254865.049149] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
```

Thats OK! By the way I can't connect to BrainLink for about 1-2 secs via

```
  bash$ sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 8C:DE:52:44:AB:23 1
```

Also I patched my Bluetooth device error (Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3404.hcd failed with error -2) following that [doc link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=194758) (without descibed module recompiling)

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/krg2ulkxdrqxham/bluetooth-hogfan.tar.gz
tar -zxvf bluetooth-hogfan.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
sudo cp fw-13d3_3404.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo cp fw-13d3_3404.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3404.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

In the result I could connect BT using channel 6 (not 1,2,3,4,5, ...). I don't know why.

```
# in real rfcomm0 became rfcomm59 by the end of experimintations.
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 8C:DE:52:44:AB:23 6
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 8C:DE:52:44:AB:23 on channel 6
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

In another shell:

```
$: sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 | hexdump -C
...
000f7f80  00 7b 02 aa aa 04 80 02  00 2c 51 aa aa 04 80 02  |.{.......,Q.....|
000f7f90  ff f9 85 aa aa 04 80 02  ff f9 85 aa aa 04 80 02  |................|
000f7fa0  00 44 39 aa aa 04 80 02  00 5b 22 aa aa 04 80 02  |.D9......[".....|
000f7fb0  00 31 4c aa aa 04 80 02  00 07 76 aa aa 04 80 02  |.1L.......v.....|
000f7fc0  ff ba c4 aa aa 04 80 02  ff 7e 00 aa aa 04 80 02  |.........~......|
000f7fd0  ff b3 cb aa aa 04 80 02  ff f9 85 aa aa 04 80 02  |................|
000f7fe0  00 1b 62 aa aa 04 80 02  00 45 38 aa aa 04 80 02  |..b......E8.....|
000f7ff0  00 36 47 aa aa 04 80 02  00 27 56 aa aa 04 80 02  |.6G......'V.....|
000f8000  00 66 17 aa aa 04 80 02  00 c5 b8 aa aa 04 80 02  |.f..............|
000f8010  00 e6 97 aa aa 04 80 02  00 91 ec aa aa 04 80 02  |................|
000f8020  ff f3 8b aa aa 04 80 02  ff d3 ab aa aa 04 80 02  |................|
000f8030  00 28 55 aa aa 04 80 02  00 36 47 aa aa 04 80 02  |.(U......6G.....|
...
```

Details of data meaning are described [here](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_communications_protocol#code_definitions_table), [here](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_communications_protocol) and [here](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=app_notes:mindwave_rf_external.pdf). Sometimes it works fine for the long time and sometimes neuro-serial-stream brings **EOF** so it's useful to read /dev/rfcomm0 since some time after disconnect. In case of connection to channel 3 I got:

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 8C:DE:52:44:AB:23 3
Connected /dev/rfcomm43 to 8C:DE:52:44:AB:23 on channel 3
Press CTRL-C for hangup
# since 10 secs it is disconnect....
Disconnected
```

Output is:

```
$ sudo cat /dev/rfcomm43 | hexdump -C
00000000  55 04 00 38 00 00 c4 55  04 00 38 00 00 c4 55 04  |U..8...U..8...U.|
00000010  00 38 00 00 c4 55 04 00  38 00 00 c4 55 04 00 38  |.8...U..8...U..8|
...
000000a0  c4 55 04 00 38 00 00 c4  55 04 00 38 00 00 c4     |.U..8...U..8...|
000000af
# (and disconnect)
```

By the bye, I try to run [NeuroPy example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NeuroPy/0.1) and got attention measure only one time:). Also I have to do next:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/rfcomm0
sudo python neuropyexample.py
```

*BrainLink was deleted from blueman paired devices during the all described experiments. Also I tested that during [TuSion](http://tusion.xyz/) via-Art neuroapp development process. Here is Facebook [community group](https://www.facebook.com/tusionapp).* My last phrase:

```
# Ubuntu 16.04 
$ uname -a
Linux SlavikBoss 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:17:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this  problem with reference of the answer by Jo Ja.
The detailed process is below:

1. hcitool scan      ---find your the adress of your brainlink. if it dosen't work, try it again, or use the bluetooh on your computer
   [here is the image of bluetooth in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0ddS.png)

   `$ hcitool scan
   Scanning ...
   B0:C0:90:B3:ED:7A   DESKTOP-JA7BUAI
   0D:00:18:A1:54:DD   BrainLink_Lite`
2. `sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 0D:00:18:A1:54:DD 2`
   -----the last number 2 means connect your brainlink on channel 2,  this may different with computers, I gusess the reason is the frequency range of Bluetooth is from 2401mhz to 2479mhz, Each channel accounts for 1MHz, 79 channels in total. So you should have a try which channel is work in your computer.

   `$ sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 0D:00:18:A1:54:DD 2
   Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 0D:00:18:A1:54:DD on channel 2
   Press CTRL-C for hangup`

   /dev/rfcomm1 or /dev/rfcomm2 or other number is ok, then rfcommX will appear in the path of '/dev/', and disappear when you disconnect.

   use the command `$ rfcomm -i --device`, it can be seen that your brainlink has been connected to 0C:DD:24:16:ED:69(your local bluetooth adress)

   `$ rfcomm -i --device
   rfcomm0: 0C:DD:24:16:ED:69 -> 0D:00:18:A1:54:DD channel 2 connected [reuse-dlc release-on-hup tty-attached]`
3. In another shell:

   `sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 | hexdump -C 
   00000000  7a aa aa 04 80 02 00 6c  aa aa 04 80 02 00 21 5c  |z......l......!\|
   00000010  aa aa 04 80 02 00 31 4c  aa aa 04 80 02 00 35 48  |......1L......5H|
   00000020  aa aa 04 80 02 00 6a aa  aa 04 80 02 ff ef 8f aa  |......j.........|
   00000030  aa 04 80 02 00 06 77 aa  aa 04 80 02 00 34 49 aa  |......w......4I.|
   00000040  aa 04 80 02 63 aa aa 04  80 02 00 0a 70 aa aa 04  |....c.......p...|
   00000050  80 02 00 17 66 aa aa 04  80 02 00 16 67 aa aa 04  |....f.......g...|
   00000060  80 02 00 24 59 aa aa 04  80 02 00 34 49 aa aa 04  |...$Y......4I...|
   00000070  80 02 00 3b 42 aa aa 04  80 02 00 31 4c aa aa 04  |...;B......1L...|
   00000080  80 02 00 6a aa aa 04 80  02 00 01 7c aa aa 04 80  |...j.......|....|
   00000090  02 00 6a aa aa 04 80 02  00 20 5d aa aa 04 80 02  |..j...... ].....|
   000000a0  00 04 79 aa aa 04 80 02  ff f5 89 aa aa 04 80 02  |..y.............|`

   if the output is like below, it means that in step2 you donot select the right channel, you should try the right channel in your computer:

   `$ sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 | hexdump -C
   00000000  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  02 00 ee 10 ff 55 02 00  |.U.....U.....U..|
   00000010  ee 10 ff 55 02 00 ee 10  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  |...U.....U.....U|
   00000020  02 00 ee 10 ff 55 02 00  ee 10 ff 55 02 00 ee 10  |.....U.....U....|
   00000030  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  02 00 ee 10 ff 55 02 00  |.U.....U.....U..|
   00000040  ee 10 ff 55 02 00 ee 10  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  |...U.....U.....U|
   00000050  02 00 ee 10 ff 55 02 00  ee 10 ff 55 02 00 ee 10  |.....U.....U....|
   00000060  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  02 00 ee 10 ff 55 02 00  |.U.....U.....U..|
   00000070  ee 10 ff 55 02 00 ee 10  ff 55 02 00 ee 10 ff 55  |...U.....U.....U|`
4. run [NeuroPy example](https://pypi.org/project/NeuroPy/0.1/) and got attention. The NeuroPy sample is work in python2, you should change it make it works in python3

   `$ sudo python neuropyexample.py`

   Don't forget run in sudo mode, and stop the `$ sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 | hexdump -C` terminal with ctrl+c in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trouble I found out that the chipset in many of the tiny new bluetooth dongles (including both the one that comes with the headset and another that I already had) cannot handle being plugged into a USB hub and must be plugged directly into the raspberry pi - even though it does show up in a list of devices.  Once I moved it from the hub bluez-simple-agent worked beautifully and without fuss.